# Setting Permalinks in wp_config or functions file?

Tags: functions, permalinks, wp-config

Hey Wordpress Development,

I help manage a small starter template for my company and I was wondering if it's possible to set the permalink structure using either the functions file or wp_config file? The goal of this would be to help standardize practices. I've done a little bit of search but didn't find anything. Is it even a good idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can customize permalink by using WordPress Rewrite_API in function file.
[See on codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)

Comment: Please explain some more and elaborate your answer. For information on writing answers please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

The permalink structure is stored in the option `permalink_structure`. You could [manually update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) or [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/option_(option_name)) this option to force a specific value.

You can try different settings and see what gets stored in this option by manually visiting the all options page `/wp-admin/options.php` and looking for `permalink_structure`.